# I am not the team agent, how do I sign a mac application with a Developer ID?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, code-signing

I am having a lot of trouble trying to sign a mac app with a developer id. We have all certificates and developer ids, but they just don't show up for me at all on XCode.

Here's what I see at the apple portal - https://www.evernote.com/shard/s26/sh/2a598526-77be-41f9-be29-5c9f8282c593/1f0c1ed1c81df05ac9c1f90c00b8c059

And this is what xcode organizer shows me - https://www.evernote.com/shard/s26/sh/059c361a-0e60-4197-a64a-b6872207f2c1/b0d3e0f9e231657eb3aa346341f8d807

It's clearly missing a lot of certificates information, since there are many more certificates at the apple developer center than at my machine. And Xcode doesn't show the Developer ID certificate for signing at all.

Any idea what's going wrong here? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Keychain Access for a key entitled 'private key'.  If you are missing your developer certificate's private key, you'll have to create a new one so you can get a new private key and matching certificate.  Once a private key has been lost, is is generally gone for good unless you made a copy.  Apple does not provide away for getting private keys for a previously made certificate.

Talk to your Team Administrator and have them create a new certificate/private key pair for you.

Comment: Ended up rebuilding my keychain and doing the signing manually, not from MonoDevelop. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the certificates, how about the private key of those certificates? You need the private key for signing.

Check your Keychain Access >> Keys and you should have both private key and its corresponding certificate or else XCode won't let you sign your App.